# Kaiming initialization for keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My model layers are using **relu activation function**. I am **using he_uniform for the kernel initializer**, but i saw ***kaiming initialization giving better result than he_uniform***. I m using keras, and keras has no kaiming initializer, how can I implement it?

Comment: Lol. Keras does not have since it already has. The initialization method you mentioned is co-authored by Kaiming He, so basically both methods you state are exactly the same thing. See [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852)

Comment: @null omg that's right, i feel such a dumb.

Comment: It's not about you. It's because of different frameworks naming it different. Tensorflow via keras uses "He", and Torch uses "Kaiming" as names. I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The confusion arise from the naming convention, the difference is naming with first name or surname. Basically, the initialization method proposed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852) co-authored by Kaiming He. The framework implementations differ, however;

Tensorflow via Keras backend uses the name `He` initilization. Torch uses `Kaiming` initilization as the method names.

In fact, the same applies also for Glorot/Xavier initialization. See [the paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) co-authored by Xavier Glorot.

Here, Tensorflow via Keras uses the surname `Glorot` whereas Torch uses the first name `Xavier`.